# How to create a column with entry count in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

Which is the best way to create a column with  the usage number, for example for the client 205 both rows are on the same day at the same hour, the "usage_number" column should be like:

[image]

The "HOURS_DIFF" column is the substraction result between "USAGE_DAY" and "SUBSCRIPTION_DATE".

I tried it with the groupby`

```
aux_df.groupby(['CLIENT', 'USAGE_DAY'])['CLIENT'].transform('size')
```

But I don see how to set the group by function to optain the count, for the client 205, the "USAGE_NUMBER" should be 1, 2 and not the total count.
    [image]

Comment: sounds like a `groupby()`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `df.gruobpy(['CLIENT', 'USAGE_DAY'])['CLIENT'].transform('size')`?

Comment: @G.Anderson I tried with min() function to get the first and then sort it.

Comment: @ansev How should I change the groupby method to obtaiing the 1, 2 (USAGE_NUMBER) and not all the usages.

Comment: `df.gruobpy(['CLIENT', 'USAGE_DAY']).cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: @ansev Doesn't work with groupby and  cumcount  function , for example for a client with 14 entries for a usage day doesn't count it from 1 to 14, only 1 to 2 and so on.

Comment: see my answer:) if USAGE_DAY is datetime then we don't need `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: Kindly do not post images. It is hard to replicate. I think you could try reading this - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Sajan thanks, I will apply the recommendations in the next posts